# kubernetes having different env for one of the replica in service

Tags: kubernetes

A Usecase where one of the service must be scaled to 10 pods.

BUT, **one of the pod must have different env variables**. (kind of doing certain actions like DB actions and triggers handling, don't want 10 triggers to be handled instead of 1 DB change), for example 9 pods have  env variable  CHANGE=0  but one of the pod has env variable CHANGE=1

Also i am resolving by service name, so changing service name is not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to solve an issue with your app using Kubernetes.

The reason I say that is because the whole concept of "replicas" is to have **identical** instances, what you're actually saying is: "I have 10 identical pods but I want 1 of the to be different" and that's not how Kubernetes works.

So, you need to re-think the reason for which you need this environment variable to be different, what do you use it for. If you want to share the details maybe I can help you find an idiomatic way of doing this using Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do what you describe is to have two separate Services.  One attaches to any "web" pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-web
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
    tier: web
```

The second attaches to only the master pod(s):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-master
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
    tier: web
    role: master
```

Then have two separate Deployments.  One has the single master pod, and one replica; the other has nine server pods.  Your administrative requests go to `myapp-master` but general requests go to `myapp-web`.

As @omricoco [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61769574/10008173) you can come up with a couple of ways to restructure this.  A job queue like RabbitMQ will have the property that each job is done once (with retries if a job fails), so one setup is to run a queue like this, allow any server to accept administrative requests, but have their behavior just be to write a job into the queue.  Then you can run a worker process (or several) to service these.